# Swift appen String to [String]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to append a String value to an array of Strings, but i'm getting this error?

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Posting a screenshot is good for showing the error message but please *always* post the actual code in the question too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a subscript on your array, and *then* calling `append` on the returned `String`. Instead, just call `append` on your array:

```
result.append(newItems.entries![i].id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your screenshot, it looks like you want to create an array from another *starting from a predefined index*.

Another way to do this without a loop would be to use `map` on a portion of the array:

```
func getFollowingArticles(index: Int) -> [String] {
    let count = newsItems.entries.count
    if index <= count {
        return newsItems.entries[index..<count].map({ $0.id })
    }
    return []
}
```

*I've also added a minimal error checking in my example.*

Answer (score -1):

> You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an
>   array.

But apparently you can use `append`.

You need to call it on the array, not on the array's last element as you do now.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: How am i suppose to add values to my array then?